# phonegap-plugin-push turn off vibration on notification

Tags: android, cordova, payload, phonegap-pushplugin

Is there a way to disable the vibration via push notification payload when notification displayed?

This is my sample payload.

```
$payload = array
        (
            'title'         => 'Title',
            'message'       => 'Message',
            'vibrate'       => 0,
            'content-available' => 1
        );
```

But vibration is still working even I set the vibrate value to 0.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Within the PushNotification.init() method you also need to set 'vibrate' to false, as it defaults to true for Android. iOS however does not have a similar setting, but setting sound to false may also work (i haven't tested this).

```
var push = PushNotification.init({
    android: {
        senderID: "12345679",
        vibrate: false
    },
    ios: {
        sound: false
    },
    windows: {}
});
```

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/API.md#pushnotificationinitoptions

Comment: Setting vibrate to false in PushNotification.init() will work. Now if we set vibrate to true in payload like this.
$payload = array
        (
            'title'         => 'Title',
            'message'       => 'Message',
            'vibrate'       => 1,
            'content-available' => 1
        );
Is this will overwrite the declaration in PushNotification.init() which is set to false? What I am trying to achieve is disable/enable the vibrate notification base on user preferences. User preferences is save in database that is why I tried to include it in push notification payload.

Comment: I'm not sure off the top of my head if that would work, i don't have an environment to test that setup currently. If you find that the payload doesn't override the PushNotification.init() value what you could potentially do is make an API request from your app to retrieve the users preference, store that in localStorage, and then use that value when calling PushNotification.init()

Comment: Thanks @jdtaylor! I will try your suggestion.

Comment: Out of interest, did you have any luck with this?

Comment: Payload don't override the declaration in PushNotification.init() in my case.